# Multiple search and find in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to SQL and I'm stuck on a multiple find in SQL.

Here I'm trying to search table1 in the three columns. But I'm stuch in trying to find two phrases. I'm trying with an OR statement.

If I remove OR LIKE '%paris%' it works but how do I find multiple words/phrases. And would this statement be case sensitive?

I'm also using MySQL to run the above.

```
SELECT * FROM `table1`
WHERE
CONCAT_WS('|',`target_1`,`target_2`,`target_3`) 
LIKE '%london%' OR LIKE '%paris%'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code  your second  condition is sintactically wrong because is missing the a part for the match

so you should repeat the condition as

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table1`
WHERE CONCAT_WS('|',`target_1`,`target_2`,`target_3`) LIKE '%london%' 
OR CONCAT_WS('|',`target_1`,`target_2`,`target_3`) LIKE '%paris%'
```

Comment: Thank you! that was it and so easy.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use regular expression, then you can also have case insensitive matching (3rd parameter to REGEXP_LIKE)

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(CONCAT_WS('|',`target_1`,`target_2`,`target_3`), 'london|paris', 'i');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should repeat the left operand and use (maybe?) multiple conditions i/o concatenating:

```
SELECT * FROM `table1`
WHERE (`target_1` like '%london%' OR `target_1` like '%paris%')
  AND (`target_2` like '%london%' OR `target_2` like '%paris%')
  AND (`target_3` like '%london%' OR `target_3` like '%paris%')
```